# Maximize $xy^4$ subject to $xe^y \leq 3e^2,~ 0 \geq y,~ x \geq 0,~ y \geq 0$

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

I do not know how I am meant to complete this problem. It is intended to be completed without reference to the Kuhn-Tucker theorem or any other Lagrangian theorem or otherwise, I expect the solution to be simple and obvious, but I have nothing

All I can think of is just using the largest values I am allowed which is making $xe^y=3e^2$ where $(x,y)=(3,2)$, however, wolfram alpha gives an oddly specific answer $(x,y)=(0.406072,3.99984)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I assume that the $0 \geq y$ constraint in the title is a typo, since you also have $y \geq 0$, so I'm going to ignore it.

The crux here is that the question is not convex, but with a few transformations it can be made convex.
Specifically, the $x e^y \leq 3 e^2$ really wants to be $\log x + y \leq 2 + \log 3$, which suggests making the substitution $z = \log x$ and transforming the problem to
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{maximise}\quad & z + 4\log y \\
\mathrm{subject\;to}\quad & z + y \leq 2+\log 3,\\
&y \geq 0.
\end{align*}
(It's easy to see that the $xy^4$ will not be maximised at $x=0$, so we don't need to worry about that case).

But now, $z + 4\log y$ is increasing in both $z$ and $y$, so the maximum must occur on the boundary.
Since the objective is $-\infty$ on the $y = 0$ boundary, it must happen on $z + y = 2 + \log 3$, where the objective is
$$
z + 4\log y
= 4\log y - y + 2 + \log 3.
$$

This is smooth, and we can check using differentiation that it is maximised at $y = 4$, so that $z = \log 3 - 2$ and so $x = 3e^{-2} \approx 0.406$.

This basically agrees with Wolfram Alpha's computation, which used numerical methods and so wasn't exact.

Comment: Could you please show how you used differentiation to find the maximum?

Comment: It's just because $\frac{d}{dy}(4\log y - y + 2 + \log 3) = 4/y - 1$, which is $0$ when $y = 4$, and must be a maximum because $4\log y - y + 2 + \log 3$ is concave.

Comment: I thought it was convex @DamianPavlyshyn, "The crux here is that the question is not convex, but with a few transformations it can be made convex."

Comment: The *problem* is convex. This means that either a convex objective is being minimized or a concave objective is being maximized (there are equivalent, since a concave maximization can be made into a convex minimization by just taking the negative) over a convex domain.

Comment: How come the problem is convex? The hessian for $xy^4$ has leading principal minor $0$ and second degree (the determinant) $-16y^6$, I thought it should be neither convex nor concave

Comment: Right - that's what I meant when I said "the question is not convex, but with a few transformations it can be made convex." That is, the problem as it is posed is not convex, but the subsequent problem that I wrote is an equivalent problem that *is* convex. You can check that the new objective $z + 4\log y$ is concave and that the domain $z + y \leq 2 + \log 3, y \geq 0$ is a convex set.

Comment: I do not think the domain is a convex set. Plotting $z+y\leq 2 + \log(3),y\geq 0, x\geq 0$ lets you draw a line that has a segment which is not in the constraint set...
But the function of the domain $z+y \leq 2+\log(3)$ is most certainly concave? (with first order hessian leader $-\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140204/discussion-between-damian-pavlyshyn-and-ripbozo).